# Added '\n' after fixed number of a multicharacter delimiter

Tags: sed

I have been tasked with parsing a very large single line text file to put into a database. The file contains huge amounts of text data (48 gigs) and was provided me in this format:

```
col1*#(%&col2*#(%&col3*#(%&col4*#(%&col5*#(%&col1*#(%&col2*#(%&col3*#(%&col4...
```

So the delimiter in this file is '*#(%&' the columns basically loop from col1-col5 in a single line.

My goal is to try to get these into a record format ie:

```
col1*#(%&col2*#(%&col3*#(%&col4*#(%&col5*#(%&
col1*#(%&col2*#(%&col3*#(%&col4*#(%&col5*#(%&
col1*#(%&col2*#(%&col3*#(%&col4*#(%&col5*#(%&
```

So I want to add a '\n' after every 5 '*#(%&'. I looked around and found a handy sed command that is able to do such [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239636/add-n-after-a-specific-number-of-delimiters):

```
sed -r 's/([^\*#\(%\&|]*\*#\(%\&){5}/&\n/g'
```

For the most part, this works, however, due to col4 being an enormous text field, I noticed that for records where a col contains any single character of *'*#(%&' ie '#', the count seems to reset and it's not behaving the way that I want. Is there a way to tweak or circumvent this from happening? I just want a new line only when the exact pattern of '*#(%&' occurs.*

Comment: Does `sed -e 's/#(%&/&\n/5' -e 'P;D'` have the same issue?

Comment: Oh wow this does fix it. What exactly is the 'P;D' doing here?

Comment: `P` is printing everything up to the first `\n`, then `D` is deleting that portion of the pattern space before implicitly repeating the "replace the 5th delimiter" command

Comment: Gotcha. Is there a reason why the '*' was removed as well?

Comment: Oops, no - I just missed that that was part of the delimiter - you should probably use `s/\*#(%&/&\n/5`

Comment: Hey I have a question, I am running into Segfault errors due to the text file being over 50 gigs. It seems like when I run this command on very large files it is reading them into memory? Do you have any suggestions on how I could overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `awk`, you could do something like:

```
gawk -v RS='\\*#\\(%&' -v ORS= '{print $0 RT};NR%5 == 0{printf "\n"}'
```

With `sed` (but beware that some `sed` implementations have a low limit on the size of lines):

```
sed 's/*#(%&/&\
/5;P;D'
```

Comment: Interesting.I was not aware of the low limit restriction that could exist with SED. I will see if this happens later today and try your awk implementation.

Comment: Question, if i want to write to a file with your awk command, how would i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F'\*#\(%&' -lane 'print join "*#(%&", splice @F, 0, 5 while @F'
```

Working:

```
 ° Split on the string `*#(%&`  it is stored in the array @F.
 ° Then, while the array still has elements in it, pluck out the leading 5, or whatever are left in the last gasp, and join these with the same string they were split on. And this is printed to stdout followed by a newline which is ensured by the `-l` option.
```